# How to show percentage in middle of bootstrap pregress bar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap progress bar heres the code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 progress-container">
     <div class="progress progress-striped active">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%">

       </div>
             </div>
               </div>
```

angular code :

```
dashboard.getPercentage = function () {
           $(".progress-bar").animate({
                width: "100%",

            }, 2500);
          }
```

its works but i want to show the percentage in the middle of the progress bar how can i do that??

Comment: turn the width into a variable. u can use the variable in the progras bar and to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `100%` as innerHTML to your progressbar DIV. and change THE innerHTML via your js as well.

Try this--

**This is how it will look**

```js
           $(".progress-bar").animate({
                width: "100%",
          
            }, 2500);
           var interval = setInterval(function () {
        $('.progress-bar').html("100%");
        
    }, 5000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         
          
<body >
  

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 progress-container">
         <div class="progress progress-striped active">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" aria-valuenow="0" style="width:0%">
    0%
           </div>
                 </div>
                   </div>
   </body>
```

Your JS might look like this. not very good with JS but tried to help

```
         $(".progress-bar").animate({
            width: "100%",

        }, 2500);
       var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $('.progress-bar').html("100%");

}, 5000);
```

Comment: thank u for your aswer..but i want to do that dynamiclly...i mean from 10% then 40% ....until 100% is that possible

Comment: yes it is possible..refer to my answer in the following question please [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422099/bootstrap-progress-bar-update-status-text-at-intervals-completed-25-50-75-1/42422557#42422557]